# How to POST a record with fk data in Strapi?

Tags: relational-database, strapi

I have a problem when I try to POST a new record.

I have a legacy app that I'm consuming with Strapi, so I didn't let Strapi create the tables, it just only use what is on the DDBB.

This one of the collection type: (enfermedadrepeticion) (go to repeticion_id)

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "connection": "atdbconnection",
  "collectionName": "enfermedadrepeticion",
  "info": {
    "name": "RepeticionEnfermedad"
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": false,
    "timestamps": false
  },
  "attributes": {
    "valor": {
      "type": "decimal"
    },
    "enfermedad_id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "valor_1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "valor_2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fechaTomaDato": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "repeticion_id": {
      "via": "repeticion_enfermedads",
      "model": "repeticion"
    }
  }
}
```

this is the model "repeticion" ... go to repeticion_enfermedads...

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "connection": "atdbconnection",
  "collectionName": "repeticiones",
  "info": {
    "name": "Repeticion"
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": false,
    "timestamps": false
  },
  "attributes": {
    "activa": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "altura": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "linea_id": {
      "model": "linea"
    },
    "ensayo_id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "esp": {
      "type": "string"
    },
   ... bunch of fields ...
    "repeticion_enfermedads": {
      "collection": "repeticion-enfermedad",
      "via": "repeticion_id"
    }
  }
}
```

My relation is: One Repeticion have 0 or N repeticion-enfermedad, via repeticion_id field.

Using this relation, when I fetch data from "Repeticion" I get one or more "Repeticion-Enfermedad".

So, when I need to update una entry in "Repeticion-Enfermedad" I PUT the data with this body :

```
body {
  enfermedad_id: 1,
  fechaTomaDato: '2021-05-05 03:29:29',
  fechaUltCambio: '2021-05-05 03:29:29',
  repeticion_id: { id: 392571 },
  valor: 60,
  valor_1: '60',
  valor_2: 'S'
}
```

and everything works fine!!

But when I try to create a record using POST, with the same body, I get a 500 error.

error Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'repeticion_id' doesn't have a default value

I try to send the body using Swagger, and I get the same error.

I try, sending "repeticion_id" field, using integer, string, object, etc, but I cant't make it work...

My Strapi version is 3.0.6
I really don't want to alter the model definition, it's working fine...

Any suggestion ??

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem.

There is nothing to do with Strapi, I have to add NOT NULL to the field in RepeticionEnfermedad table.
It looks like Strapi first tries to create a record in that table, and then updates the recently added record...

I leave my answer in case someone got the same problem.

Chiao!